# is there a good tool for viewing the permissions in AD?

Tags: active-directory, permissions, groups

I want to be able to see a nice picture of nested groups in AD. Are there any products that do that for me?

Comment: Do you mean the actual ACLs on AD Objects, or AD Security Group permissions assigned to something like a file share?

Comment: I was thinking AD Security Group permissions assigned to a file share but both would be nice :)

Answer (score 1):

I created a HTA script which displays the nested groups in a GUI. I hope this helps.

[image: membertree]

You can download it at: http://zeda.nl/t03

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but my application [SetACL Studio](http://helgeklein.com/setacl-studio/) has a very nice user interface and is designed to replace the built-in Windows ACL Editor.

It displays permissions on files and folders, registry keys, network shares, printers, services and WMI objects. Changing permissions and ownership is easily possible, too, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a windows machine, you can use the `dsget group` command with `-members -expand` to expand the groups with membership via nesting.  I'm not sure if this is what you want, but I hope it helps in some way, if you have not already found a more elegant solution.  As a warning, this code is off the top of my head, as I no longer have access to a Windows machine:

```
$all_members = []
$nested_groups = []

dsquery group -limit 0 | ?{$_ -imatch "cn=$your_groupname,"} | dsget group -members -expand | % {
    # these are all the members of the group, including those groups with
    # membership via nesting

    # you could omit the users by extracting the group name from $_
    # and testing that they are a group

    $possible_group = $_

    if ( $possible_group -imatch "cn=([^,]+)," ) {
        $possible_group_name = $matches[1]
        $all_members += $possible_group_name

        # this condition may or may not work.  if not, get sample output
        # from calling dsquery group on a user and use that as the condition
        # instead

        if ( dsquery group -name $possible_group_name -ne $null ) {

            # alternatively, you could make each member of $nested_groups
            # an array, make this a function, and recursively collect
            # the entire nesting of this and all sub-groups

            $nested_groups += $possible_group_name
        }
    }
}

write-host "groups in $your_groupname, via nesting"

$nested_groups | % {
    write-host "`t$_"
}

Write-host "groups and users in $your_groupname, via nesting"

$all_members |  % {
    write-host "`t$_" 
}
```

I hope the code works for you, and if not, there is probably a small typo from bad memory on my part.

Good luck! :)